# Number of common chords of the two parabolas

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

How can we find common chords to the parabolas  $$ (y-2)=(x-3)^2$$ and $$(x-2)=(y-3)^2$$ without drawing graphs.

What i have done is i have subtracted both of them and i got

$$(y-x)=(x-y)(x+y-6)$$ $\implies$

$$(x-y)(x+y-5)=0$$ Hence

$x=y$ and $x+y=5$ are the two common chords. How can find whether there are any other chords

Comment: If you try to solve by substitution and get to something like the quartic $x^4 - 12x^3 + 52x^2 -97x +66=0$ (suggesting four possible intersections) you could use the insight is that the two parabolas intersect when $x=2$ and $y=3$ and again swapping these values: these are your $x+y=5$ cases.  So then you can factorise it to $(x-2)(x-3)(x^2-7x+11)=0$, leading to the four points of intersection and ${4 \choose 2} =6$ chords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint.

Find the point of intersection of the two line with one parabola. You find $4$ points $A,B,C,D$. All the combinations $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$, $CD$ are common chords. And there are no other since these points are the only common points of the two parabolas.